# Quais são as técnicas para se fazer animações baseadas em scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento, animação

Estou interessado em criar sites com animação comandada pelo scroll (ex.: [Kano](http://www.kano.me/)), onde os conteúdos vão sendo animados e substituídos conforme o rolamento da página.

Quais são as técnicas para facilitar esse tipo de programação?

Comment: +1 "alguém sabe se existe **alguma técnica** para facilitar esse tipo de programação?"

Comment: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: Existem varias libs de Javascript que fazem esse trabalho e te ajudam a não fazer isso nativamente, existem varias estrategias para este problema. Nesse caso que você passo do site Kano, navegando pelo código HTML, podemos ver que ele foi feito utilizando a lib [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/), no entanto já existe uma nova versão de plugin [ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)

Comment: O site linkado usa isto: http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/. Mas eu gostaria de ver respostas que explicassem de fato quais são as técnicas para se fazer isso, como enfatizou o @JorgeB.

Comment: Segue um **[demo interessante](http://www.cabletv.com/the-walking-dead)** e um **[tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/game-style-parallax-scrolling-zombie-edition/)**

Answer (score 60):

### A técnica

O efeito que pode ser visualizado no link colocado na pergunta é comummente conhecido por "Parallax Scrolling".

### Parallax

O termo "parallax" refere-se ao movimento aparente dos objetos quando vistos de diferentes posições. A técnica foi originalmente utilizada em jogos de vídeo 2D em imagens de fundo com movidos mais lentos do que imagens de primeiro plano, criando uma ilusão de profundidade.

Apesar de ser algo que está na "moda" no que respeita ao desenvolvimento de web-sites, na realidade é algo que remota à 30 anos atrás como é o caso do jogo [Moon Patrol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Patrol).

### Como funciona

Web-sites com o efeito Parallax fazem uso de CSS3 e script para criar animações multiplano, introduzir novos elementos e criar movimento para além do eixo Y à medida que se faz scroll na página.

O principio base é criar a ilusão de profundidade tridimensional através da deslocação de elementos na página a diferentes velocidades.

As coisas que estão no primeiro plano tem um movimento mais rápido do que as coisas no fundo, dando assim a impressão aos visitantes de que o site contém uma profundidade entre os seus elementos.

### Fórmula

Tudo gira em torno da manipulação da posição do elementos, o scroll da página e a velocidade a que as coisas acontecem. Essencialmente, os scripts existentes para facilitar a criação de páginas com efeitos "Parallax" baseiam-se numa formula simples:

- Camada 1

  Camada de objectos mais próximos (deslocação mais rápida):

  > v<sub>1</sub> = c;

  Define-se que a velocidade da camada 1, ou mais próxima, tem a velocidade igual a c.
- Camada 2

  Camada de objectos mais afastados (deslocação mais lenta)_

  > v<sub>2</sub> = c/2;

  Para a camada 2, ou mais afastada, definimos que a sua velocidade é metade da velocidade da camada 1.
- Mais camadas

  Á medida que vamos adicionando mais camadas, vamos manipulando a velocidade das mesmas em função da velocidade da camada mais próxima, obtendo assim velocidades diferente para cada camada:

  > v<sub>3</sub> = c/3;
  >   v<sub>4</sub> = c/4;
  >   ...
  >   v<sub>99</sub> = c/99;

Conseguimos então com uma formula igual à em cima apresentada, animar a velocidade de cada camada com deslocações diferentes transformando um cenário estático num cenário com animações multiplano dando a ilusão de profundidade.

Para este esquema de camadas:

[image: Camadas]

<sup>[Fonte da imagem.](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parallax-scroll-example-2.png)</sup>

Conseguimos a seguinte animação:

[image: Camadas com Parallax]

<sup>[Fonte da imagem.](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parallax-scroll-example.gif)</sup>

---

## Aplicação prática

Transpondo a explicação dada em cima para o cenário da web, as animações tem por base uma formula igual ou semelhante à apresentada, mas dependendo da técnica aplicada, a animação pode ser "Parallax" ou algo mais elaborado.

### Técnica 01 - Efeito Base

Um site com "Parallax Scrolling" tem os elementos de primeiro plano a deslocarem-se com o scroll da página de forma natural. O efeito fica aplicado aos elementos de segundo plano (geralmente imagens de fundo), onde os mesmos são deslocados a uma velocidade inferior para dar a sensação de profundidade.

[Exemplo no codePen](http://codepen.io/SaraVieira/pen/fKmHC)

HTML

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<section>
    <h1>Home page</h1>
    <p>We are a fairly small, flexible design studio that designs for print and web. We work flexibly with clients to fulfil their design needs. Whether you need to create a brand from scratch, including marketing materials and a beautiful and functional website or whether you are looking for a design refresh we are confident you will be pleased with the results.</p>
    <p>We offer the following services:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Branding</li>
        <li>Logos</li>
        <li>Websites</li>
        <li>Web applications</li>
        <li>Web development – HTML5, CSS, jQuery</li>
        <li>Content Management Systems</li>
        <li>Responsive Web Design</li>
        <li>Illustration</li>
        <li>Business cards</li>
        <li>Letterheads and compliment slips</li>
        <li>Flyers</li>
        <li>Mailers</li>
        <li>Appointment cards</li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Sub page</h1>
    <p>Before you choose us to take on your project you will probably want to know a bit more about us, so meet the team:</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixum.com/500/600"/>
    <p>Ross has over 10 years experience in the industry. He is our Creative Director, digital designer, web designer and front-end developer. He is also pretty good with a sketchbook. Before starting the company Ross worked as a designer and studio manager for a design house who boasted a number of big name clients. Ross has brought his vast experience from this role to the work he does now.</p>
    <p>Monica is Ross’ sister, our Art Director and specialises in graphic and print design. She has also worked with some big names and her designs have won her a number of industry awards.</p>
    <p>Rachel and Chandler are our Junior Designers. Rachel is a web designer with knowledge of HTML and CSS and supports Ross on projects. Chandler has just finished his Graphic Design degree and enjoys continuing to learn from Monica and building his experience.</p>
    <img src="http://lorempixum.com/500/600/sports"/>
    <p>Joey and Phoebe focus on bringing new business to the company. They have won a number of big clients recently and both also have qualifications in project management to ensure that the projects run smoothly from start to finish.</p>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
.bg {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/USFbNpC.jpg') repeat;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
}
section {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

jQuery

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  parallax();
});
function parallax(){
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.bg').css('top',-(scrolled*0.2)+'px');
}
```

<sup>Este exemplo foi criado por Sara Vieira e publicado no [webdesignerdepot](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/how-to-create-a-simple-parallax-effect/).</sup>

Como pode ser visto pelo código de exemplo, o truque é feito colocando a imagem de fundo com uma posição fixa `position:fixed` e através da execução de uma função sempre que a barra de rolagem da página é deslocada. A referida função manipula o valor de `top` da imagem, deslocando a mesma em 1/5 da rolagem feita, obtendo assim uma deslocação a velocidades diferentes entre os elementos de primeiro plano e o elemento de segundo plano.

### Técnica 02 - Manipulação Avançada

As técnicas mais avançadas de Parallax Scrolling seguem o conceito original, mas levam as animações mais além, controlando não só a deslocação dos elementos, mas também a sua posição na tela e/ou o seu estado de visibilidade.

[Exemplo em Nasa Prospect](http://nasaprospect.com/)

Nesta animação podemos ver que não só o primeiro plano tem uma velocidade diferente do segundo plano, mas como à medida que fazemos scroll, existe elementos que são introduzidos na página e outros removidos e/ou manipulados em relação à tela.

Isto é tudo controlado com o principio base apresentado no exemplo simples que tem por base a formula apresentada na introdução ao Parallax nesta resposta.

### Técnica 01 - Manipulação Invertida

Por último, começa também a ser popular o Parallax Scrolling invertido, cujo principio do mesmo a mesma técnica base, mas neste caso, ao realizar scroll na página, deslocam-se os elementos no eixo do X ao invés do eixo do Y.

Os objectos são assim manipulados com recurso a JavaScript, de forma a que a sua posição se altere em função do eixo do X criando uma animação na horizontal.

[Exemplo na Pixxelfactory](http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/)

---

<sup>**Notas:**

A resposta foi elaborada no sentido de explicar com detalhe o que é Parallax Scrolling, de onde veio o conceito, quais as suas aplicações práticas mais comuns no mundo dos web-sites e como tudo funciona nos bastidores.

Foi colocado um único exemplo de código com vista a apresentar a simplicidade com que o efeito pode ser gerado.</sup>

Comment: vi hoje esse vídeo da Disney e lembrei desse post. Talvez valesse a pena usá-lo como ilustração do assunto? :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdHTlUGN1zw

Answer (score 20):

Já usei o [superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) para fazer isso. É bem simples de usar.. o próprio exemplo deles é muito intuitivo. Ele usa a biblioteca [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/) para trabalhar com a animação que por sinal é fantástica.

**O html ficaria assim:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <title>SUPERSCROLLORAMA</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">    
</head>
<body class="simple-demo">
    <div id="content-wrapper">

        <div id="examples-1">
            <h2 id="fade-it">Fade It</h2>
            <h2 id="fly-it">Fly It</h2>
            <h2 id="spin-it">Spin It</h2>
            <h2 id="scale-it">Scale It</h2>
            <h2 id="smush-it">Smush It</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="_/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/jquery.superscrollorama.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**E o javascript assim:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var controller = $.superscrollorama();
    // Anima os elementos individualmente utilizando greensock
    controller.addTween('#fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('#fade-it'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}));
    controller.addTween('#fly-it', TweenMax.from( $('#fly-it'), .25, {css:{right:'1000px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
    controller.addTween('#spin-it', TweenMax.from( $('#spin-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, rotation: 720}, ease:Quad.easeOut}));
    controller.addTween('#scale-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#scale-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, fontSize:'20px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, fontSize:'240px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
    controller.addTween('#smush-it', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#smush-it'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, 'letter-spacing':'30px'}, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, 'letter-spacing':'-10px'}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), 0, 100); // 100 px offset for better timing
});
```

você pode ver o [site oficial](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) ou [clonar pelo git](https://github.com/johnpolacek/superscrollorama)

Comment: +1 muito boa resposta

Comment: +1 excelente resposta!

Answer (score 4):

Pode se usar uma animação de vários frames e imagens,isso não seria muito eficiente em termos de utilização de internet,mas poderia determinar qual frame deve ser o atual com a relação scroll atual da página `document.body.scrollTop` com o tamanho total `document.body.scrollHeight`.

Calculando a porcentagem atual,poderia ser criado animações usando apenas javascript puro.

```
a = (document.body.scrollTop/document.body.scrollHeight)*100
```

Se você quiser que uma div se mova 500px por exemplo,calcula a porcentagem atual da página e calcula a porcentagem do 500,esse número será onde a div deverá estar atualmente.

Comment: Poderia incluir um exemplo simples na resposta?