# Parallax e Pin elements

Tags: posicionamento, parallax

estou procurando solução para realizar um efeito de parallax e fixar alguns elementos a medida que passo por sessões da tela.

A ideia disto é juntar as partes de um calçado e montar ele a medida que o scroll rola.

Alguém indica algum?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23202/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-t%C3%A9cnicas-para-se-fazer-anima%C3%A7%C3%B5es-baseadas-em-scroll

Answer (score 0):

**baixe a biblioteca jquery a partir da versão 1.11.1 e utilize o código abaixo no css:**

```
#parallaxBar{
     max-width: 100%;
     height:750px;
    background-color:#004c82;
    background: url('enderecolocaldoarq') no-repeat 50% 0 fixed;
    position: relative;   

      /* -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px); */
}
```

**e  este srcript abaixo eu prefiro colocar no html na pagina aonde vc quer o efeito:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $window = $(window);
            //Captura cada elemento section com o data-type "background"
            $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
                var $scroll = $(this);   
                    //Captura o evento scroll do navegador e modifica o backgroundPosition de acordo com seu deslocamento.            
                    $(window).scroll(function() {
                        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $scroll.data('speed')); 
                        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
                        $scroll.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });    
                    });
           });  
        }); 
 </script>
```

**Abaixo, a section responsável pelo efeito construido:**

```
<section id="parallaxBar" data-speed="6" data-type="background">
        <!-- IMAGEM SOBRE O PARALLAX no CSS "parallaxBar" e etc-->      
</section>
```