# Desenhando o Top Gear

Tags: java, javafx, jogos

Estou tentado fazer um jogo igual ao Top Gear (SNES) para adquirir um pouco de conhecimento sobre jogos 2D, só que me veio uma dúvida a respeito das pistas: elas são retas, curvas ou imagens?

Eu estou usando JavaFX. Se eu tentar usar curvas(`QuadCurve`) é difícil fazer as linhas na pista onde muda a cor para uma cor mais clara ou escura. Se for usar retas vai ficar "estranho", e se usar imagens vai "inundar" a tela por causa de poucas mudanças.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Esses jogos de corrida em 2D até onde eu saiba renderizam cada linha da tela independentemente das demais. Se você observar uma captura de tela do jogo (estou assumindo que você se refere ao primeiro jogo da série) verá que não há uso de curvas ou retas, mas um padrão irregular, quando você olha na vertical. Quando olha na horizontal, por outro lado, todas as linhas são retas!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você observar outros jogos do mesmo gênero - como o Outrun da Sega - verá que a mesma técnica é empregada, com níveis variados de sofisticação. O resultado é uma projeção em perspectiva com um único [ponto de fuga](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_de_fuga), onde linhas horizontais (x) e verticais (y) se mantém paralelas conforme o mundo real, somente a profundidade (z) não conserva o paralelismo (e a propósito, se a pista é renderizada linha por linha, os objetos mais complexos são formados por imagens, via [parallax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23584/215)).

Como a resolução dos jogos dessa época era baixa (i.e. poucos pixels por unidade de medida) então isso pode ser feito de forma relativamente eficiente[1]. Não conheço JavaFX, mas vou dar um exemplo usando `canvas` em JavaScript (em geral as bibliotecas de desenho 2D têm API bastante semelhantes, creio que não terá dificuldade em adaptar):

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
var delta = 0;

var g = ["#00AA00", "#00FF00"]; // verde escuro / verde claro
var rw = ["#FF0000", "#FFFFFF"]; // vermelho / branco
var lg = ["#AAAAAA", "#777777"]; // cinza claro / cinza escuro

function render() {
  // Limpa o cenário com a cor do céu
  ctx.fillStyle = "#3333FF";
  ctx.fillRect (0, 0, 300, 150);
  
  // Para cada linha de pixels na tela
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
    // Quanto mais longe, mais finas as linhas
    var n = i * Math.log((i+20)/20)
    
    // Limpa a linha com a grama (alterna verde claro e escuro a cada 20 pixels)
    ctx.fillStyle = g[Math.floor((n+delta)%40/20)];
    ctx.fillRect(0, 150-i, 300, 1);
    
    // Coloca a lateral da pista (alterna vermelho e branco a cada 10 pixels)
    ctx.fillStyle = rw[Math.floor((n+delta)%20/10)];
    ctx.fillRect(10+i, 150-i, 300-2*(10+i), 1);
    
    // Coloca o centro da pista (alterna cinza claro e escuro a cada 20 pixels)
    ctx.fillStyle = lg[Math.floor((n+delta)%40/20)];
    ctx.fillRect(20+i, 150-i, 300-2*(20+i), 1);
  }
  
  // Avança pela pista (nesse exemplo, na velocidade do render; na prática, usar o tempo)
  delta ++;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

Colocar curvas pra esquerda e direita é fácil: basta deslocar a linha desenhada conforme a posição da última linha (como melhor representar a pista, não sei te dizer... Nesse exemplo, vou usar um array com as variações laterais do ângulo a partir de uma certa distância percorrida).

```js
// Representando uma pista
var pista = [[300,0],[50,1],[200,0],[50,-1],[500,0],[50,3]];

function lateral(pos) {
  // Acha o tracho da pista em que estamos
  for ( var i = 0 ; pos > pista[i%pista.length][0] ; i++ )
    pos -= pista[i%pista.length][0];
  
  // Tenta dar uma atenuada no ângulo, no começo e final da curva
  var ret = pista[i%pista.length];
  return ret[1] * Math.min(20, pos, ret[0]-pos)/20;
}
             
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
var delta = 0;

var g = ["#00AA00", "#00FF00"]; // verde escuro / verde claro
var rw = ["#FF0000", "#FFFFFF"]; // vermelho / branco
var lg = ["#AAAAAA", "#777777"]; // cinza claro / cinza escuro

function render() {
  // Limpa o cenário com a cor do céu
  ctx.fillStyle = "#3333FF";
  ctx.fillRect (0, 0, 300, 150);
  
  // Para cada linha de pixels na tela
  var lat = 0;    // Deslocamento lateral em relação à última linha
  var angulo = 0; // Variável auxiliar pra calcular lat
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
    // Quanto mais longe, mais finas as linhas
    var n = i * Math.log((i+20)/20)
    
    // Posição da linha na pista em relação ao carro
    var pos = Math.floor(n + delta);
    angulo += lateral(pos);
    lat += Math.floor(10 * Math.sin(angulo*Math.PI/180));
    
    // Limpa a linha com a grama (alterna verde claro e escuro a cada 20 pixels)
    ctx.fillStyle = g[Math.floor((n+delta)%40/20)];
    ctx.fillRect(0, 150-i, 300, 1);
    
    // Coloca a lateral da pista (alterna vermelho e branco a cada 10 pixels)
    ctx.fillStyle = rw[Math.floor((n+delta)%20/10)];
    ctx.fillRect(10+i+lat, 150-i, 300-2*(10+i), 1);
    
    // Coloca o centro da pista (alterna cinza claro e escuro a cada 20 pixels)
    ctx.fillStyle = lg[Math.floor((n+delta)%40/20)];
    ctx.fillRect(20+i+lat, 150-i, 300-2*(20+i), 1);
  }
  
  // Avança pela pista (nesse exemplo, na velocidade do render; na prática, usar o tempo)
  delta ++;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

Da mesma forma, pode-se simular subidas e descidas variando a "altura" da linha. Ou usar um pequeno valor aleatório para criar as "ranhuras" nas faixas. Etc. Note que ambos os exemplos são bem "crus" (fiz em alguns minutos[2], meio que na tentativa e erro) e algumas distorções são bem aparentes. Mas é um bom exemplo do que se pode fazer com somente umas 50 linhas de código, e é consistente com o que se usava na prática nesse tipo de jogo.

Essa técnica (simular 3D usando 2D) é às vezes chamada de [2.5D](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,5D_%28computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_gr%C3%A1fica%29) (ou 2½D, ou perspectiva ¾; não confundir com o conceito matemático de fractal). Não conheço detalhes da técnica específica usada nos jogos de corrida, mas pude notar - pela minha dificuldade de fazer esse pequeno exemplo ficar minimamente apresentável - que um conhecimento e aplicação da geometria é essencial para implementá-la com sucesso. É isso que vai determinar qual a distância que cada linha representa, qual relação entre o ângulo da curva e o deslocamento lateral da pista, como corrigir o fato dos ângulos maiores "esticarem" as linhas laterais (fazendo parecer que o carro andou pra trás), etc.

Mas no final das contas, o meio de desenhar a pista dados os pontos de referência é esse. Pelo menos nos jogos antigos, é claro - nada impede que você renderize a cena de outras formas, por exemplo usando esse tal de `QuadCurve` (ou mesmo uma [curva de Bézier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curva_de_B%C3%A9zier) mais geral, se Java der suporte) usando os pontos de referência calculados pelo mesmo método.

---

Notas:

[1]: Hoje em dia também dá pra fazer isso de forma eficiente, através da programação dos *fragment shaders* direto na GPU, mas isso extrapola um bocado o escopo da pergunta.

[2]: Ok, o exemplo básico saiu em uns poucos minutos, mas quando tentei fazer a curva acabei me "agarrando" por um bocado a mais de tempo... :P