# Como aplicar efeito de parallax numa imagem?

Tags: javascript, css

Eu não sei se vou conseguir explicar minha dificuldade, mas vamos lá;

Observe a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clico na barra de rolagem o que acontece?

Consigo visualizar o resto da pagina, porém a imagem de fundo não fica congelada, ela fica fixa por causa das configurações que fiz no CSS.

O que seria uma imagem congelada?

Ao clicar na barra de rolagem para movimenta-la para baixo a imagem ficaria fixa, mas ao invés disso ela acompanha.

Vou tentar explicar melhor.

O objetivo dessa ação é ao clicar na barra de rolagem e mexe-la para baixo a imagem ficasse fixa, como ela não está fixa o que acontece?

consigo chegar a ter o final da pagina na parte inferior da pagina e encontrar o final da imagem, e esse não é o objetivo, como ela está se comportando dessa forma se tiver muito conteúdo as informações serão incluídas e passar da imagem, deixando uma má estética da pagina.

Antecipadamente quero pedi desculpas por não explicar com clareza minha dúvida, mas caso alguém tenha duvida no que expliquei tentarei novamente tentar explicar, é porque eu não encontrei nenhum exemplo na internet que pudesse colocar-lo aqui para que tivesse uma ideias, eu sei que tem algo relacionado a  efeito de parallax.

Acredito que possa ser feito de várias formas, ou por CSS ou por JavaScript.

/////////////////////////////////////////

Encontrei um exemplo e coincidentemente é bem parecido com meu site.
Esse é o efeito que queria colocar na minha pagina, porém gostaria de uma dica de como posso iniciar a implementação dessa função.

http://pt.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1595?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpt.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fbusiness%2F4&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=3&category=business&metaSiteId=

Comment: Já viste esta pergunta? -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23202/129

Comment: acabei de ver agora, mas gostaria que você observasse a minha postagem, acabei de atualizar e encontrei a ideia que estava precisando, dá uma olhada para ver se consegue me ajudar.

Comment: peço desculpas, é porque aquela implementação não resolveu, peço mil desculpas, vou começar por lá.

Comment: @wladyband nao precisa pedir desculpas, se tem algo que não entendeu, basta comentar lá. É que ficar tentando perguntar a mesma coisa de jeitos diferentes é pior, e não vai resolver o problema. Tente explicar onde está com dificuldade que podemos tentar ajudar.