# Efeito de transição na imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu não sei explicar muito bem como é o nome desse efeito, mas alguém pode me dar uma luz de como se fazer? Ou o nome disso pelo menos, achei bem legal, queria implementar na página que estou fazendo, mas não tenho ideia do que fazer.

No máximo imaginei dar um "position: fixed" na imagem, mas tá bem longe do que eu acho que é o correto pra aplicar esse efeito.

O efeito em questão é o da essa imagem em laranja, que você desce a página e ela meio que se completa, não sei explicar.

http://www.lancamentosdanetflix.com/

Comment: Referes-te à imagem ficar fixa enquanto "scrollas"?

Comment: Há uma resposta muito boa sobre isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23202/129

Comment: Sim, essa mesmo.

Comment: Ok, nesse caso dá uma olhada a essa outra resposta, é bem completa.