# Como colocar dalay de rolagem em um background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria que o bg de minha section tivesse um certo delay na velocidade da rolagem para se diferenciar da rolagem padrão da página. Alguém sabe como posso fazer?

Comment: Esclareça melhor a pergunta e inclua o que vc já tentou fazer.

Comment: Talvez você esteja perguntando sobre [efeito parallax](http://materializecss.com/parallax.html), não?

Comment: Isso, vacilei aqui, poderia ter dito.

Comment: Neste caso [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23202/quais-são-as-técnicas-para-se-fazer-animações-baseadas-em-scroll) pode te ajudar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo de efeito *parallax* usando jQuery. Basta adicionar a classe `.parallax` nas `section` que você deseja o efeito:

```js
$(function(){
   $('.parallax').each(function(){
      var $sec = $(this);
      $(window).on('scroll',function() {
         var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop()/3);  // no lugar de "3", quanto maior o valor, mais lento o movimento do background
         $sec.css('background-position', '0 '+ yPos +'px');
      }); 
   });
});
```

```css
/* CSS apenas para exemplo */
.parallax {
    color:#FFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

#sec1{
   background: url(https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg);
}
#sec2{
   background: url(https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/hrc-tigre-siberiano-2-jpg_21253111.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer interdum molestie lorem, eu facilisis ipsum bibendum nec. Aliquam blandit augue in magna efficitur tristique. Sed semper velit odio, euismod lacinia felis tincidunt id. Sed suscipit hendrerit purus, non tempus velit ultrices sit amet. Mauris condimentum facilisis massa, eget fermentum leo ullamcorper sit amet. Vestibulum dictum ut nunc a suscipit. Sed id ipsum consectetur, vestibulum erat vitae, ultricies nulla. Quisque dignissim orci vel nisi fermentum iaculis sit amet at velit. Aliquam sagittis nulla nulla, a pellentesque justo mattis vitae. Proin lacinia nisi elit, non dapibus ex vehicula vitae.</p>
<section id="sec1" class="parallax">
   <h3>Texto 1</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer interdum molestie lorem, eu facilisis ipsum bibendum nec. Aliquam blandit augue in magna efficitur tristique. Sed semper velit odio, euismod lacinia felis tincidunt id. Sed suscipit hendrerit purus, non tempus velit ultrices sit amet. Mauris condimentum facilisis massa, eget fermentum leo ullamcorper sit amet. Vestibulum dictum ut nunc a suscipit. Sed id ipsum consectetur, vestibulum erat vitae, ultricies nulla. Quisque dignissim orci vel nisi fermentum iaculis sit amet at velit. Aliquam sagittis nulla nulla, a pellentesque justo mattis vitae. Proin lacinia nisi elit, non dapibus ex vehicula vitae.</p>   
</section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer interdum molestie lorem, eu facilisis ipsum bibendum nec. Aliquam blandit augue in magna efficitur tristique. Sed semper velit odio, euismod lacinia felis tincidunt id. Sed suscipit hendrerit purus, non tempus velit ultrices sit amet. Mauris condimentum facilisis massa, eget fermentum leo ullamcorper sit amet. Vestibulum dictum ut nunc a suscipit. Sed id ipsum consectetur, vestibulum erat vitae, ultricies nulla. Quisque dignissim orci vel nisi fermentum iaculis sit amet at velit. Aliquam sagittis nulla nulla, a pellentesque justo mattis vitae. Proin lacinia nisi elit, non dapibus ex vehicula vitae.</p>
<section id="sec2" class="parallax">
   <h3>Texto 2</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer interdum molestie lorem, eu facilisis ipsum bibendum nec. Aliquam blandit augue in magna efficitur tristique. Sed semper velit odio, euismod lacinia felis tincidunt id. Sed suscipit hendrerit purus, non tempus velit ultrices sit amet. Mauris condimentum facilisis massa, eget fermentum leo ullamcorper sit amet. Vestibulum dictum ut nunc a suscipit. Sed id ipsum consectetur, vestibulum erat vitae, ultricies nulla. Quisque dignissim orci vel nisi fermentum iaculis sit amet at velit. Aliquam sagittis nulla nulla, a pellentesque justo mattis vitae. Proin lacinia nisi elit, non dapibus ex vehicula vitae.</p>   
</section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer interdum molestie lorem, eu facilisis ipsum bibendum nec. Aliquam blandit augue in magna efficitur tristique. Sed semper velit odio, euismod lacinia felis tincidunt id. Sed suscipit hendrerit purus, non tempus velit ultrices sit amet. Mauris condimentum facilisis massa, eget fermentum leo ullamcorper sit amet. Vestibulum dictum ut nunc a suscipit. Sed id ipsum consectetur, vestibulum erat vitae, ultricies nulla. Quisque dignissim orci vel nisi fermentum iaculis sit amet at velit. Aliquam sagittis nulla nulla, a pellentesque justo mattis vitae. Proin lacinia nisi elit, non dapibus ex vehicula vitae.</p>
```