# Animações em conjunto

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de perguntar se há algum método de se realizar animações ao mesmo tempo com JavaScript e html. Exemplo: faço um bonequinho cair e, ao clicar nele ele some enquanto continua a cair. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23202/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-t%C3%A9cnicas-para-se-fazer-anima%C3%A7%C3%B5es-baseadas-em-scroll

Comment: Acredito que não fui muito específico, quero realizar uma animação dento de outra animação.